# C# Powerpoint Hyperlink Color

Tags: c#, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am trying to access powerpoint's Hyperlink's and Followed Hyperlink's Color, but I can't find these properties under `TextRange.Lines().Characters().ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink`

Does anyone know how can I access these colors?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks follow the Theme colors for the slide.

To modify the hyperlink color for a slide (in VBA) you'd do:

```
With oSl ' assuming an object reference to the slide you want to work with
  .ThemeColorScheme.Colors(msoThemeHyperlink).RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```

msoThemeHyperlink is a vba Long (C# Integer, I imagine) = 11

msoThemeFollowedHyperlink = 12

Comment: I do not know nothing about VBA, I have tried slide.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(msoThemeHyperlink) but it did not work.

Comment: msoThemeHyperlink would have to be defined as a constant = 12 or you could just use the value 12.  Beyond that, I can't help much, as I don't use C#.